# How To Respond With a JSON Body on 415 (Unsupported Media Type) in ASP .NET Core Minimal APIs?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, exception, minimal-apis

If you call an ASP .NET Core Minimal APIs endpoint without a `Content-Type` header, you get an empty body response with status code 415. I need to handle this error and respond with some error JSON. I can't get the endpoint to respond with anything other than an empty string. Also, the exception handler doesn't intercept anything.

Here is a sample app and tests that explain the problem.

API

```cs
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestProject1")]

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.Configure<RouteHandlerOptions>(o => o.ThrowOnBadRequest = true);

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapPost("/hi", ([FromBody] Request request) => "Hello World!");
app.MapPost("/throwerror", ([FromBody] Request request) => true ? throw new Exception("Ouch") : "");

app.UseExceptionHandler(handlerApp => handlerApp.Run(async context =>
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Threw Error");
}));

app.Run();

record Request(int Id);
```

Tests

```cs
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
namespace TestProject1;

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    //This test doesn't pass. I think it should hit the exception handler and set the body to "Threw Error"
    //What I need to achieve is the ability to give a meaningful error message in the body if the consumer
    //doesn't specify a Content-Type header 
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestHiRespondsWithTextFromExceptionHandlerOnNoContentType()
    {
        var factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>().WithWebHostBuilder(builder => { });
        var client = factory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://localhost/hi"), 
            //No content type
            new StringContent( "{ \"Id\": \"123\" }", Encoding.UTF8));
        var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //this would prove the exception handler is handling this
        Assert.AreEqual("Threw Error", body);
    }
    
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestSuccessRespondsWithHelloWorld()
    {
        var factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>().WithWebHostBuilder(builder => { });
        var client = factory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://localhost/hi"), 
            new StringContent( "{ \"Id\": \"123\" }", Encoding.UTF8,"application/json"));
        var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Assert.AreEqual("Hello World!", body);
    }
    
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestThrowErrorRespondsWithTextFromExceptionHandler()
    {
        var factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>().WithWebHostBuilder(builder => { });
        var client = factory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://localhost/throwerror"), 
            new StringContent( "{ \"Id\": \"123\" }", Encoding.UTF8,"application/json"));
        var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //this proves the exception handler is handling this
        Assert.AreEqual("Threw Error", body);
    }
}
```

Notice that the first test fails because it never hits the exception handler. It's as though there is some middleware that is executing before any other middleware and it never throws an exception. It just responds with 415 `Unsupported Media Type` before giving me a chance to do anything. ***How do I hook into this middleware to respond with a body?***

The bottom two tests pass.

Comment: Why do you want this? The current behavior is *more* specific and cheaper than what you ask. The request is rejected by ASP.NET Core *before* the API even starts to process it, probably before it even starts to read the body. That's a *good* thing - you don't want to waste CPU and RAM to process a bad message. This isn't just a 400 (Bad Request), it's an Unsupported media type

Comment: You may be able to change the API behavior through the [ApiBehaviorOptions.ClientErrorMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apibehavioroptions.clienterrormapping?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-apibehavioroptions-clienterrormapping) property in [ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvccoremvcbuilderextensions.configureapibehavioroptions?view=aspnetcore-7.0), mapping 415 to your own ClientErrorData content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add a custom middleware like this:

```cs
public class CustomUnsupportedMediaTypeMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CustomUnsupportedMediaTypeMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        int statusCode;
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
            // 405 does not throw an exception
            statusCode = context.Response.StatusCode;
        }
        // `context.Response.StatusCode` is not set yet, it'll still be 200 here and in `finally`
        catch
        {
            // log, etc
            statusCode = 500;
        }

        // if (context.Response.StatusCode == 415)
        if (statusCode > 400)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Threw Error");
        }
    }
}
```

And use it before the routes, like:

```cs
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseMiddleware<CustomUnsupportedMediaTypeMiddleware>();

app.MapPost("/hi", ([FromBody] Request request) => "Hello World!");
app.MapPost("/throwerror", ([FromBody] Request request) => true ? throw new Exception("Ouch") : "");

app.Run();
```

I got the initial idea from ChatGPT:
https://chat.openai.com/share/8784c09d-d068-4214-b40d-be7117c877a3
But this was not enough for the `Ouch` case, because:

- The 415 does not throw an exception, only sets the status code
- The custom exception (`ouch` case) not set the set the status code, only throws an exception

So, I played with it to make all tests pass:

[image: Tests passing]

#### Update

The OP, @christian-findlay, asked me in answer comments to change this to the `app.Use` method as it's more conventional way in new API world, as per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/middleware?view=aspnetcore-7.0#:~:text=Copy-,app.Use((,-context%2C%20next)%20%3D%3E%0A%7B).

So, the use of the middleware and the creation of the API routes beceomes:

```cs
var app = builder.Build();

// app.UseMiddleware<CustomUnsupportedMediaTypeMiddleware>();
app.Use(OverrideErrors);

app.MapPost("/hi", ([FromBody] Request request) => "Hello World!");
app.MapPost("/throwerror", ([FromBody] Request request) => true ? throw new Exception("Ouch") : "");

app.Run();
```

Where the `OverrideErrors` middle is implemented almost the same way:

```cs
async Task OverrideErrors(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
{
    int statusCode;
    try
    {
        await next(context);
        // 405 does not throw an exception
        statusCode = context.Response.StatusCode;
    }
    // `context.Response.StatusCode` is not set yet, it'll still be 200 here and in `finally`
    catch
    {
        // log, etc
        statusCode = 500;
    }

    // if (context.Response.StatusCode == 415)
    if (statusCode > 400)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Threw Error");
    }
};
```

The only difference in this particular code is that our function needed to be defined before the `Request` record or else C# complains.

And it still works:

[image: app Use success]

Comment: Can confirm that this works. I ended up using the Use() extension instead of the MVC style UseMiddleware extension.  Any chance you could link to this document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/middleware?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and add a note that you you can use either of these approaches?  You also need to await next(context) in the same way you did here.

Comment: @ChristianFindlay Great point. Done. Please see the answer and check if it's more correct.

Comment: Great work and very helpful. Thankyou